# D3.js Heatmap: How to read from a nested json and create a Heatmap using D3

Tags: html, d3.js

I have been trying for a couple of days now to read a JSON file with data and generate a heatmap from it. The JSON contains the frequency of git commits by day, for every week for 52 weeks.The data in the JSON (frequency each day) is nested hence I do not know how to extract the data and get the code to represent it. I am really new to do and I do not understand what I am missing or doing wrong. Would really appreciate if anyone can help me out. I read several links, but none of them deals with JSON and I am also having trouble understanding it. I would like to create 52 rows representing a week and 7 columns for each day of the week which I already have. The rectangles just dont reflect the frequency. I am not sure how to do that. A sample of the data I have and the code I have done so far is as such:

Code:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>
    <script>
        var url = "data/git-commit-frequency.json"
        var color = ["#ffffd9","#c7e9b4","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"]

        d3.json(url, function (data) {
            let gridSize = 50;
            let width = (gridSize + 1) * 7; 
            let height = (gridSize + 1) * data.length;

            // define range!!!
            var x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 7])
            .range([0, width]);

            //52 weeks
            var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, data.length])
            .rangeRound([height, 0]);

           let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
           .attr("width", width)
           .attr("height", height)

            // Generate rows for each json object
            var rows = svg.selectAll('.row')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr("transform", function(d, i){ 
                 return "translate(0," + y(i) + ")"
            })

            // Generate rects for the array of days per object
            let box = rows.selectAll("rect")
             .data(function(d){ return d.days })
                 .enter()
                 .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i); }) 
                .attr("width", gridSize)
                .attr("height", gridSize)
                .style("fill", 'black')
                .attr("class", "bordered");
            })
    </script>
</body>
```

JSON:

```
    [
      {
        "days": [
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          1,
          0
        ],
        "total": 1,
        "week": 1457827200
       }
     ]
```

I have 52 of such JSON objects in the file.

Comment: Isn't this the same as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916634/d3-heatmap-using-nested-json-data-how-to-create-grids

Comment: Tht just helps me to create the grids. Which I already mentioned in my post that I can achieve it. As I am new to d3, I do not really know how to attach the values to the rectangles. I have tried to apply the examples online to my code but after that my page just becomes blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code attaches values to the rects with this piece of code, and specifically the `.data(function(d){ return d.days })`

```
let box = rows.selectAll("rect")
             .data(function(d){ return d.days })
                 .enter()
                 .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i); }) 
                .attr("width", gridSize)
                .attr("height", gridSize)
                .style("fill", 'black')
                .attr("class", "bordered");
            })
```

Each appended rect will have one of the values from the days array (eg 0, or 1).

You can inspect this in the browser console (right click on the rect, select Inspect and go to Properties > Rect > **data** and you will see what values have been appended to that element.

From there, you can typically access the value using an anonymous function within setting the style or attr of your rect. For example, to set colour:

.style("fill", function(d) { return d === 0 ? "grey" : "black"; })

which sets rects with 0 value to be grey, and anything else black. Although you as you get more complex mappings, using d3-scale becomes valuable.